# Shared Schedules & Always On Availability

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, high-availability, alwayson, ssrs-2019

We are running a report server on a SQL 2019 Always on AG in MS Azure.

When you go to see the Shared Schedules in Reporting Services and SQL Server is on the secondary replica, RS cannot see these shared schedules, you receive the error:

> An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.

When you switch back to the other replica it works fine.

I've tried creating them again when on the secondary replica but it doesn't allow you to commit the creation of the schedule.

Is there something that needs to be done so both Replicas can see the Shared Schedules?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "and SQL Server is on the secondary replica"? Do you mean that you've failed over the AG with the reporting services databases to the secondary node and it is now the primary? Make sure you completed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/reporting-services-with-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#bkmk_steps_to_complete_failover) after the failover.

Comment: Also read [Report Server Behavior When a Failover Occurs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/reporting-services-with-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#bkmk_failover_behavior).

Comment: Yes when you failover over the AG and the secondary becomes the primary, the schedules are not copying over and cannot be accessed.